# PySFTP and get_r using Python - "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

So I have a "simple" process that needs to go out and grab data from another server and then copy the directory (and all sub-directories) to my server

The code is as follows:

```
import pysftp


dbfs_path = '/dbfs/mnt/aaa/bbb/output/{}/'.format(dbutils.widgets.get("run_name"))
remote_path = '/mst_bbb/{}/output/{}/'.format(bucket,dbutils.widgets.get("run_name"))
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None   

srv = pysftp.Connection(host=host_name, username="xxx",password="yyy",cnopts=cnopts)

srv.get_r(remote_path,dbfs_path)
```

It was working fine until I realized that sometimes I had to get the same directories more than once and would throw off an error that

> the directory already exists

No problem, I thought and did the following:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(dbfs_path)
```

And then re-ran the code

But now I get a much different error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-9f782d79e03f> in <module>()
     12 
     13 srv = pysftp.Connection(host=host_name, username="xxx",password="yyy",cnopts=cnopts)
---> 14 srv.get_r(remote_path,dbfs_path)

/databricks/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.pyc in get_r(self, remotedir, localdir, preserve_mtime)
    309             self.get(fname,
    310                      reparent(localdir, fname),
--> 311                      preserve_mtime=preserve_mtime)
    312 
    313     def getfo(self, remotepath, flo, callback=None):

/databricks/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.pyc in get(self, remotepath, localpath, callback, preserve_mtime)
    247             sftpattrs = self._sftp.stat(remotepath)
    248 
--> 249         self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=callback)
    250         if preserve_mtime:
    251             os.utime(localpath, (sftpattrs.st_atime, sftpattrs.st_mtime))

/databricks/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.pyc in get(self, remotepath, localpath, callback)
    767             Added the ``callback`` param
    768         """
--> 769         with open(localpath, 'wb') as fl:
    770             size = self.getfo(remotepath, fl, callback)
    771         s = os.stat(localpath)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/dbfs/aaa/bbb/output/run_job/./mst_bbb/pri1/output/run_job/date=2017-12-01/2017-12-01_output_0.csv.gz'
```

Any ideas what might be causing this problem? I can't figure it out

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the target directory of `get_r` (`localdir` argument) has to exists. pysftp won't create it for you.

While your call to `shutil.rmtree` removes not only directory contents, but the directory itself too.

Recreate the directory afterwards:

```
shutil.rmtree(dbfs_path)  
os.mkdir(dbfs_path)
```

---

Though actually, I do not understand your original problem. I do not see why would you be getting the *"the directory already exists"* error. Maybe you should ask about that problem, rather than implementing an inefficient workaround.